# ShFileOperation disk-size abort option

Tags: delphi, shell, abort

I am using ShFileOperation to copy files to an SD card and it is working fine, almost!

I have some large files, 5GB and greater. When the SD card is empty this all progresses fine. But, when I am updating the files on the SD c ard, ShFileOperation will check remaining disk size and if the file is larger than free-space it will show a "No room" dialog and abort.

The problem arises when the file will be overwriting an existing one and is probably only 3MB or 4MB larger with new stuff. The ShFileOperation does not first check if the destination file exists before checking for disk space.

I have checked all available Flags on the MSDN site and the only one I can find is FOF_NOERRORUI but that is a little too brutal and totalitarian for me. Killing off all error messages just to overcome one problem.

Is there any way I can get ShFileOperation to not do that disk-space check, but still declare serious errors if they occur?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're checking target files beforehand, to find out if it's an overwrite, you might as well delete the target, in which case shell's warning will be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can get ShFileOperation to not do that disk-space check, but still declare serious errors if they occur?

You can use `FOF_NOERRORUI` to suppress the error UI. Which is indeed exactly what you want. But then you need to provide UI for any errors, since you asked the system not to. That flag essentially means, "let me take charge of reporting errors."

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried that but it still will not copy it over the existing file. It hides the error message, but then does nothing. The current issue is with a 10.8GB existing file, an 11GB new file, 8GB free space. In actual fact there is 7.8GB of free space.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, I would suggest using `CopyFileEx()` for each file, utilizing its progress callback to update your own progress dialog as needed.

Comment: Thanks Remy, I am dong something like that at the minute, but I liked using the ShellAPI as it gave the new win7/8 graphic dialog for long copies. A Progressbar looks stagnant as it groans along for 10 minutes with very big files. You have to position the mouse cursor at the end of the moving part to verify it is actually moving.

Comment: One nice thing about using CopyFileEx() to display your own status dialog is that you can show 2 progress bars - one for how many files have been copied, and another for how many bytes of the current file have been copied.  The first bar may increment slowly if you have a large list of files, but the second bar should fly by quickly showing real-time activity.